# Conditional Sum in non fixed range in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, array-formulas

I will pose the issue with an example. Attached is a print screen of an excel excerpt.

I would like to sum the numbers in column B that matches 2 conditions (green rows in excel). First one: column F equal to "closed". Second one: column C equal to those numbers which in turn matches the following condition: column F equal to "Partial Sold".

I try with the following matrix formula, but I only got the sum that matches these conditions: column F equal "closed" and column C equal "1".

```
=SUMPRODUCT($D$66:$D$86,IF($F$66:$F$86="Closed",1,0),IF($C$66:$C$86=INDEX($C$66:$F$86,SMALL(IF($F$66:$F$86="Partial Sold",$C$66:$C$86),ROW(1:20)),1),1,0))
```

[Excel Data: This is a print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTQXK.jpg)

[image: OP sample data]

Comment: re: *'I would like to sum the numbers in column B'* - There are no numbers in column B. Your supplied formula suggests that this may be column **D** instead.

Comment: Have you tried to skip the `SUMPRODUCT` part? Just the If should be enough... if I got you right

Comment: Jeeped, you are right. I would like to sum numbers in column D.

Comment: Dirk, I do not completely understand how the sum would be performed if I skip the sumproduct function. I have tried to use sumifs, but I have the same issue I explain in the main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can produce this with an array¹ formula based on [SUM](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) and [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) with a second nested INDEX delivering the numbers from column C that match *Partial Sold*. Due to the array formula's cyclic calculation, you have to **flip** the nested conditional array with the [TRANSPOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027) in order that it does not process **in-line** with the other factors.

[image: sum_for_1579]

The array¹ formula in H4 is,

```
=SUM(INDEX(D3:D23*(F3:F23="Closed")*(C3:C23=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(C3:C23*(F3:F23="Partial Sold"), , ))), , ))
```

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Comment: Jeeped, thanks! As you show in your image, it works. TRANSPOSE function has an interesting role here!

Comment: Jeeped, may be you can also help me in the other question I have. I posted it 3 months ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482369/twinkle-dots-in-parallel-programming

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the image. It is my quiet protest for sample data that is delivered by image and requires retyping in order to become useful in proofing a solution. I'll edit and post the actual formula used in a few days.

Comment: Don´t concern about that. It´s OK to me. Besides, you are right. It would be easier if I originally provide editable data. The point is that´s my second post and I don´t know how to do... yet! :)

Comment: Jeeped, I was trying to modify a little bit that formula. Now I do not want a simple summation, but a summation of rates. Let me explain it over: I would like to sum the numbers in column D that matches 2 conditions (green rows in excel). First one: column F equal to "closed". Second one: column C equal to those numbers which in turn matches the following condition: column F equal to "Partial Sold". At the same time, EACH number in the previous summation might be divided by the number of column D which matches "Partial Sold" in column F. I will add the example in next comment ...

Comment: @Federico - That sounds like a new question. wadr, I'm not partial to *after-the-fact* modifications that make valid answers to the original question invalid. Your feedback is appreciated but imho, your recent additional condition would make this a new question.

Comment: There is the example with the table/figure I attached in the main question: (4510 / 9820) + (6500 / 9820) + (9100 / 15400) + (2388 / 2995) + (12400 / 9820) + (2904 / 5855). My cells would be: (D69 / D66) + (D70 / D66) + (D76 / D74) + (D82 / D78) + (D83 / D66) + (D84 / D72). Your cells would be: (D6 / D3) + (D7 / D3) + (D13 / D11) + (D19 / D15) + (D20 / D3) + (D21 / D9)

Comment: Done. I've posted another question